# Splitting up text with BeautifulSoup by certain HTML structures

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to split up some HTML based on a certain pattern.

A specific part of the HTML has to be divided into 1 or more parts or text arrays. The way that I am able to divide this HTML is by looking at the first `<strong>` and a double `<br />`. All the text that is between these two tags has to be put into a list and iterated over.

How can this easily be solved?

So I want the following HTML:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <!--# of ppl associated with place-->
        This is some kind of buzzword:<br />
    <br />
    <!--Persontype-->
        <strong>Jimbo</strong> Jack            <br />
Some filler text            <br />
More weird stuff
            <br />
Unstructured text        <br />
        <br />
        <strong>Jacky</strong> Bradson            <br />
This is just a test            <br />
Nothing but a test
            <br />
More unstructured stuff        <br />
        <br />
        <strong>Junior</strong> Bossman            <br />
This is fluffy
            <br />
As I would expect        <br />
        <br />
</div>
```

Split into following portions.

First part:

```
        <strong>Jimbo</strong> Jack            <br />
Some filler text            <br />
More weird stuff
            <br />
Unstructured text        <br />
        <br />
```

Second part:

```
        <strong>Jacky</strong> Bradson            <br />
This is just a test            <br />
Nothing but a test
            <br />
More unstructured stuff        <br />
        <br />
```

Third part:

```
        <strong>Junior</strong> Bossman            <br />
This is fluffy
            <br />
As I would expect        <br />
        <br />
</div>
```

Comment: what did you try so far ?

Comment: @aberna, i tried to `find_all('strong')` and iterating through all the siblings with `next_siblings`, but thats where i get stuck.. It got me nowhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic solution is by using join, prettify and split. Basic idea is to convert it in a text and separate the portion of interest.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(text))
for i in soup.prettify().split('<!--Persontype-->')[1].split('<strong>'):
    print '<strong>' + ''.join(i)
```

The text file is:

```
text= '''
<div class="clearfix">
    <!--# of ppl associated with place-->
        This is some kind of buzzword:<br />
    <br />
    <!--Persontype-->
        <strong>Jimbo</strong> Jack            <br />
Some filler text            <br />
More wierd stuff
            <br />
Unstructured text        <br />
        <br />
        <strong>Jacky</strong> Bradson            <br />
This is just a test            <br />
Nothing but a test
            <br />
More unstructured stuff        <br />
        <br />
        <strong>Junior</strong> Bossman            <br />
This is fluffy
            <br />
As i would expect        <br />
        <br />
</div>
'''
```

Output is:

> **Jimbo**        Jack    
>     Some filler text    
>     More wierd stuff    
>     Unstructured text    
>     
>       
>       **Jacky**        Bradson    
>     This is just a test    
>     Nothing but a test    
>     More unstructured stuff
>   
>     
>       
>       **Junior**        Bossman    
>     This is fluffy    
>     As i would expect

Comment: So far so good! Is there any way that i can remove all tags? Afterwards i want to do a i.split("\n"), so i have it in a list of lines.

Comment: Use this print function print  ''.join(re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', i))